# Помогите определить тип события

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-типы

Есть форма:

```js
function handleAddOp (e: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement, MouseEvent>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ....
}

return (
    ....
        <form onSubmit={handleAddOp}>
            <br />
            <h2><p>Добавить оператора</p></h2>
            <label>
                Название: <input value={inputOp} onChange={onChangeSearch} placeholder="Максимум 10 символов"/>
            </label><br />
        </form><br />
        <div>{message2}</div><br />
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleAddOp}>Добавить</Button><br/><br/>
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}>Закрыть</Button>
    .....
)
```

Когда я добавил onSubmit, тип события стал не актуален и ts пишет, что ему нужно React.FormEvent, но когда я изменяю событие, у меня отваливаются уже кнопки, которые находятся вне формы. Я конечно могу прогнуться и сунуть кнопки в форму, но я бы хотел этого избежать. Подскажите тип для моей ситуации.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Как узнать тип пропса React компонента?

1. Например при написании `<button onClick />` посмотреть в сплывающей подсказке (ctrl+space если сама не появилась), далее стрелочка рядом с именем, если по ней кликнуть - появится окошка с описанием
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
2. В вашем случае, можно сделать так: написать `onSubmit={event => null}` а затем навести мышку на `event`

   ```
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   // 
   {//TEST
       // (parameter) event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>
       const form = (<form onSubmit={event => null}></form>);
       // (parameter) event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>
       const button = (<button onClick={event => null} />)
       // (parameter) event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
       const inp = (<input onChange={event => null} />)
   }
   // 
   // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   ```

### Как использовать одну и ту же ф-ю в двух разных компонентах?

В вашем случае, в функции `handleAddOp` событие может быть `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>` или `React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>`.

В TypeScript это будет выглядеть так `React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>` (используется оператор логическое И)

- https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#intersection-types

```
function handleAddOp(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ....
}
```

### - ,-

[песочница там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChyB6CuAMQEkANAWQFEAuOQcRBAhEED4QOQLIgfOIHYQQAwgcQFwgvQDwggfhBegXhBArCCLuAGi7ClcQGwggFhBAiiDc4gJhA4AAwgA7AMIAbYGgDWF0gBMkaeyiJwAbr5wAEIArjAwNhzI6DAAdDS2ADwo1gCeAHwA3OSYodYYwDZwABap7vZIAILu7gDyYAAUSNHE8TTQICz%20SNYwSQASACpMADIdUF2VIL0wGXAAPohtcUwQoQDOSN2zgyOjYRE2LNOzmmub2z19GQCUcADepHAvcEhxYETXMAAiSJgoUL2GCNW45V5wKhwOIwuKkAC%20pGAfSQUABaCQcAAirYIAAFHBgDaPZ6vGYbDYoADmSAATBxUmlwa8NiUIAB3NbuFD2DgAIwgEEqqWZLy2MAAymzORBuby4I1WRyuTz%20YLhdZ7gBeeaM0VwZFgcINDgbGBQZFU-U2Wxlaw0iWoKBoEocZrfVqxOK21I0nZ9PZjOjWI0wE5IGY3bW69I5RFoGxm7G4z0YBLJHH4wkbeZahUPODkyk02maJUyuVlpCS6Uq%20yaQ3GsCaG12h1Ol1weHRkkQogwUJQawKpIZUkQl5JTCdOA2CWhPkgYAwLUPO0Vaq1BrwscTvdwJIlWkZQAoILxAIwgYlMgA4QbiAGRA4Lw5MpAAIgYj4b6SFCPu-3EKSPh8kg9gZIAuCBiCIphiIo17KBwSSNvAgT2KESCroh26znYbZoQ8ra%20kgjq%20C68JwGAPgYmy9ieFAWoAESADggYiSIAgiDXjIgDCIDIcAAIwAAxwGxMimLwgDcILwph0ZCGRfoBwG-nuX7TpMCkTkk7jAP4GQPEW1J0vCX4aVp45qYckTDoEFqpCudGfKAvhpFJNqOC4q7rpUNT1GAO5npeN73l%20Zk2DJfJQNJSShdJJn-kFFm%20MA1n0dy9qok5dguc4q6gnAOpwOKUrKrKPKNAAhOWda3DugDoIMxL6ANIgAUULFqlfncCKkEAA)

```
import React from 'react'


// FIXME: что это за компонент, что он ждёт в `onClick`
declare var Button: React.FC<any>;

function handleAddOp(e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement> | React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement, MouseEvent>) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // ....
}
interface QCoProps {
    message2: any;
    showModal: boolean;
    setShowModal: (showModal: boolean) => any;
    inputOp: string;
    onChangeSearch: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => any;
}
const QCo: React.FC<QCoProps> = ({ message2, showModal, setShowModal, inputOp, onChangeSearch }) => {
    return (<>
        <form onSubmit={handleAddOp}>
            <h2>Добавить оператора</h2>
            <label>Название: <input value={inputOp} onChange={onChangeSearch} placeholder="Максимум 10 символов" /></label>
        </form>
        <div>{message2}</div>
        <Button variant="primary" onClick={handleAddOp}>Добавить</Button><br /><br />
        <Button variant="danger" onClick={() => setShowModal(!showModal)}>Закрыть</Button>
    </>)
}
```